# return the query with tables related in a selected way

Tags: laravel

I have an api that returns my data like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 1,
    "titulo": "Lorem ipsum larabil",
    "categoria_id": 6,
    "created_at": "2020-10-30T10:33:08.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-30T10:33:08.000000Z",
    "categoria": {
      "id": 6,
      "parent_id": null,
      "nombre": "NombreCategoria",
      "slug": "nombrecategoria",
      "created_at": "2020-10-30T10:32:50.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-10-30T10:32:50.000000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

The query on the controller is this:

```
$encuestas = Encuesta::with('categoria')->where('categoria_id', $id)->get();
return $encuestas;
```

I would like the query to return only the id, title and name of the category .

I have tried to do this but it does not work:

```
$encuestas = Encuesta::with('categoria')->select('id', 'titulo', 'categoria')->where('categoria_id', $id)->get();
```

or

```
$encuestas = Encuesta::with('categoria')->select('id', 'titulo', 'categoria.nombre')->where('categoria_id', $id)->get();
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel [Eager Loading Specific Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)

```php
$encuestas = Encuesta::select('id', 'titulo')
    ->with('categoria:id,nombre')
    ->where('categoria_id', $id)
    ->get();
```

it should return data like

```json
[{
    "id": 4,
    "titulo": "Lorem ipsum larabil",
    "categoria": {
        "nombre": "NombreCategoria"
    }
}]
```

Comment: This returns the null categoria

Comment: the same result

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns

For you it would be:

```
$encuestas = Encuesta::with('categoria:id, title, name')->where('categoria_id', $id)->get();
```